# Android arm emulator timing out when trying to instal app

Tags: android, android-emulator, bitrise

I'm trying to get an android app to build and run UI test in the emulator on Bitrise.io.

I'm consistently getting this error when the script is trying to install the app on the emulator:

```
11:12:03.398 [QUIET] [system.out] :app:installDebug
11:12:09.000 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager] Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
```

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it's not connecting.

First i download the needed SDK

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter addon-google_apis-google-23
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-23
```

then I create the emulator

```
echo no | android create avd --force --name main --target "android-23" --abi "google_apis/armeabi-v7a"
```

Then i start the emulator

```
/tools/emulator -avd main -skin 1920x1080 -no-boot-anim -no-audio -no-window
```

Then I try to start the test
./gradlew bitrise --continue --debug

Where bitrise is a script that essentially does this
./gradlew clean assembleDebug installDebug installDebugAndroidTest check connectedCheck

The whole error log in case it means anything to someone.

```
11:12:00.706 [QUIET] [system.out] :app:packageDebug
11:12:03.392 [QUIET] [system.out] :app:assembleDebug
11:12:03.398 [QUIET] [system.out] :app:installDebug
11:12:09.000 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager] Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
11:12:10.236 [QUIET] [system.out] 
11:12:10.237 [QUIET] [system.out] Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'main(AVD) - 6.0' for app:debug
11:12:22.444 [ERROR] [system.err] Unable to install /bitrise/src/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
11:12:22.450 [ERROR] [system.err] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
11:12:22.451 [ERROR] [system.err]   at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:64)
11:12:22.452 [ERROR] [system.err]   at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:904)
11:12:22.453 [ERROR] [system.err]   at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:137)
11:12:22.454 [ERROR] [system.err]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.install(InstallVariantTask.java:134)
11:12:22.455 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:12:22.456 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11:12:22.457 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:12:22.458 [ERROR] [system.err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11:12:22.459 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
11:12:22.460 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
11:12:22.461 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
11:12:22.462 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
11:12:22.463 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
11:12:22.464 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
11:12:22.465 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
11:12:22.466 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
11:12:22.467 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
11:12:22.468 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
11:12:22.469 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
11:12:22.472 [QUIET] [system.out] :app:installDebug FAILED
11:12:22.479 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
11:12:22.480 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
11:12:22.481 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
11:12:22.482 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
11:12:22.483 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
11:12:22.484 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
11:12:22.484 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
11:12:22.485 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
11:12:22.486 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
11:12:22.487 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
11:12:22.488 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
11:12:22.489 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
11:12:22.490 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
11:12:22.491 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
11:12:22.491 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
11:12:22.491 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
11:12:22.491 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
11:12:22.491 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
11:12:22.491 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
11:12:22.491 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
11:12:22.491 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
11:12:22.491 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
11:12:22.492 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
11:12:22.492 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
11:12:22.492 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
11:12:22.492 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
11:12:22.492 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
11:12:22.492 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
11:12:22.492 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
11:12:22.492 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
11:12:22.493 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
11:12:22.493 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
11:12:22.493 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
11:12:22.493 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
11:12:22.493 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
11:12:22.493 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
11:12:22.493 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
11:12:22.494 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
11:12:22.494 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
11:12:22.494 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
11:12:22.494 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
11:12:22.494 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
11:12:22.494 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
11:12:22.495 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
11:12:22.495 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
11:12:22.495 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
11:12:22.495 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
11:12:22.495 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
11:12:22.496 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
11:12:22.496 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
11:12:22.496 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
11:12:22.496 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:12:22.496 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11:12:22.507 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:12:22.507 [ERROR] [system.err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11:12:22.507 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
11:12:22.507 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
11:12:22.507 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err] 
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err] 
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err] * What went wrong:
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err] Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
11:12:22.508 [ERROR] [system.err] > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException
```

**Update**
After upgrading to the android-24 and reducing the emulator screen resolution, the problem went away.

Comment: What screen resolution do you use to get it to work?

Comment: CAn't remember exactly. I think 800*640 or something similar. In the end we ditched the idea of running the UI test in the emulator on bitrise though. The thing is just way too slow

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Start Android emulator` step to boot the emulator. The thing is, simply calling `emulator -avd ...` will only start to boot the emulator, but it will not wait for the emulator to be fully booted and to be ready for use.

The "Start Android emulator" step (https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-start-android-emulator) implements this functionality, as well as other minor checks/workarounds.

Comment: Yes, i actually do use the bitrise step, i just copied the output to show what commands were run.